# Android scaling copy of image instead of changing source image

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I have the following code for getting small sized avatar image:

```
    Bitmap b= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
    File file = new File(selectedImagePath);
    Bitmap out = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 128, 128, false);
    FileOutputStream fOut;
    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        b.recycle();
        out.recycle();
    }
```

The problem is that after executing this code, my image in gallery is rescaled too, but I must leave it without any changes.
I tried to use copy of Bitmap image like this:

```
Bitmap bmp2 = b.copy(b.getConfig(), true);
Bitmap out = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bpm2, 128, 128, false);
```

or

```
Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(b);
Bitmap out = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bpm2, 128, 128, false
```

But my original image still changes. How could I obtain new, independent copy of this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the image from **"selectedImagePath"** and then your output file points to the same path, when you call `compress()` you overwrite your original image.

Try making a new name for the resized image.

```
fOut = new FileOutputStream(renamedFile);
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem.